# MySQL - max in group of results

Tags: mysql, sql

So maybe my question title is not most relevant but I'm not good in sql and I will need to learn it for sure (So hint for some book would be very useful)

Anyhow I got table which has following (important) columns:

```
user_id,username,revenue
```

and records like this:

```
1,john,39
2,mark,53
3,philipp,7
1,john,17
2,mark,3
2,mark,100
```

I need to get user who has the biggest revenue, so I need to get all rows, calculate total earnings and print the user who has the biggest revenue in total.

Any hints ;) ?

Comment: Are you missing something in your sample data? Why `user_id` 3 has different username (philipp and mark)?

Comment: sorry typo, usernames are uniqe

Comment: Then update your question. The current answer is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` :

```
SELECT user_id, username, SUM(revenue) FROM table
GROUP BY user_id /* add ', username' ONLY if two different usernames with the same user_id is a possible case */
ORDER BY SUM(revenue) DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

With this, you'll calculate the revenue for each user, you order by decreasing total and get only the first one, so that you have the highest revenue.

Comment: This will result the user with the id = 3: `philipp` as the max total revenue with total = `107`, apart from it is wrong total, it should be the user `mark` with total revenue = 156.

Comment: Because you'd rather group by name instead of id ? What if two guys have the same name ?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - Actually there is some error in OP's given data. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581407/mysql-max-in-group-of-results#comment-20351162).

Comment: No this is in the query you posted, and this is happenning because you are grouped by the user_id and selecting the username which is different for the same userid.

Comment: And yes, I think the last line should have "philipp" as username.

Comment: I see your point @MahmoudGamal, I added something in my answer to cover this case then.

Comment: In this situation I agree with @Mahmoud Gamal, because id and names does not match so it is better to go with username.

Comment: @tsabz - I know the problem is in the OP data, so grouping by `user_id` and `username` will not solve the issue either because there are usernames having different ids, So I think group by username and selecting only the username with out id [**like in this**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bbe4/2) will be fine in this case.

Comment: Actually in every other DBMS this query would be rejected with an error because of incorrect usage of the `group by` clause. MySQL does accept it but simply returns random values. See here for an explanation: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html